# documents4j - c.d.job.FileSourceFromInputStreamSource error

Tags: documents4j

We have been using `documents4j` for over 2 months now. We today have started hitting this error today:

> WARN  [pool-2-thread-2] c.d.job.FileSourceFromInputStrea mSource -
>   Could not delete temporary file C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2\14
>   70613946677-0\2486f960-da00-402b-92a7-469a29958a34\temp453

It "locks" up the documents4j converter and we need to close it (force close) and delete the word system task and restart it to get it to work again.

We use the Remote converter implementation.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Is this error reoccurring? If it ran stable for two month now, maybe you are putting too much presure on the converter? It can help to reduce the concurrency level.

Comment: Hi Rafael ... We figured it out ... Word needed to be activated with Microsoft ... perhaps it forces it after 2 months ...